# Get 404 error when trying to install the nodemon package

Tags: node.js, installation, nodemon

I get a 404 error when trying to install the nodemon package.

```
PS C:\Users\Fo0ola\Desktop\SERVER-SIDE> npm install -g nomdemon
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nomdemon -
Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'nomdemon@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Fo0ola\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-05T19_11_02_879Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You misspelled `nodemon` as `nomdemon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, you wrote `nomdemon`  instead of `nodemon`

Try running

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: oops, it looks like a typo.. thanks buddy !

Comment: you're welcome, can you mark my answer as correct, please?